# django: order a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have a view like this:

```
def profile (request):
    articles = Post.thing.all()
    newSet = set()
    def score():
        for thing in articles:
            Val = some calculation...
            ....
            newSet.update([(thing,Val)])      
    score()
    context = {
     'articles': articles.order_by('id'),
     'newSet':newSet,
    }
    return render(request,'my_profile/my_profile.html',context)
```

and the outcome is a Queryset which looks like this:

```
set([(<thing: sfd>, 1), (<thing: quality>, 0), (<thing: hello>, -1), (<thing: hey>, 4), (<thing: test>, 0)
```

I am now trying to order the set by the given Values so its a list which starts with the highest Value, but when i do `newSet.order_by/filter/split/join` 
it does not work since `'set' object has no attribute join/filter/split`.

Can anybody give me a hint how to sort the querySet i could not find anything helpful on my own.

I need this to work out in the view so it cannot/should not be done in the model. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Sets are not ordered. Why are you using one? Why not a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the outcome is a Queryset which looks like this

Actually this is a `set` (python builtin type), not a `QuerySet` (django's orm type).

`set` is an unordered collection type. To "sort" it you first have to turn it into a `list` - which is actually as simple as `newlist = list(newset)`, 
then you can sort the list in-place with `newlist.sort()`. Since you want this list to be sorted on it's items second elements, you'll need to use the `key` argument to tell `sort` on what you want to sort:

```
newlist.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
```

or you can just change your `score()` function to store `(score, obj)` tuples instead in which case `list.sort()` will naturally do the RightThing (it will sort your tuples on their first item).

While we're at it: instead of calling `newSet.update()` with a list of a single item, you can just use `newSet.add()` instead, ie:

```
def score():
    for thing in articles:
        val = some calculation...
        ....
        newset.add((thing, val)) 
        # or if you don't want to specify a callback
        # for `list.sort()`:
        # newset.add((val, thing))
```

And finally: do you really need a `set` at all here ? Why not using a `list` right from the start ?

Comment: thanks it worked out with "newlist = list(newset)". I tried to start with newSet = list() and  newSet.add([(thing,Val)]) bit i got the same fail message that list() does not have an attribute "add".

Comment: Of course... a `list` is not a `set` so the API is not the same. What you're looking for is `list.append()` (and you may want to take a couple hours learning to use the basic Python data types too, it might save quite some time).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be slightly confused here between a set,  a list and a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/)? A set is unordered, while a list is not. Sets don't expose the methods you listed above (filter, order_by, split, join). A QuerySet is a Django-specific class which has many useful methods.

I think it would be simpler to make `newSet` a list of tuples, and then to order that list by `value` using `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`.

If your calculation of val is eligible for it though, I'd recommend using [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then doing away with `newDict` or `newSet`, and simply pass back the queryset of articles, which would be much simpler, maybe faster, and orderable by using `articles.order_by('value')`. If you post the calculation of `val`, I'll try to tell you if that's feasible.

Comment: yes you are right I totally missed the difference. I started to read about the differences between sets,lists and QuerySets. Thanks for pointing that out. And thanks for the comment i really appreciate your support :)